# How do you set the selected element of a select html element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, select

I have a `<select>` html element and I have users create the objects that are then dynamically included in the drop down select list. I want the select menu to be set to newly created object. How do I set the selected element with jQuery?

Comment: Can you Share the code you're using to add the new option to the drop down list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#mySelect > #idOfTheOptionIWant").attr("selected", "selected");
```

The reverse being (to deselect an option):

```
$("#mySelect > #idOfTheOptionIWant").removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your  element selected, simply set the option's 'selected' property to true. Example:

Where your select element has id="foo" and the element in the list you want to be selected is element:

```
$("#foo").element.selected = true;
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: what should `element` be? the name or value?

Comment: @Justin I've edited the answer to include what to do if you have the value of the element you want to select.

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '288' of undefined`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry... I made a mistake; the array index you want to use is the index of the item in the list, not the value of that item.

Answer (score 0):

Set `newOption.selected = true`.